# Checking a CheckBox in DataGrid should Check all checkboxes in RowDetails

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid Shipments and Products. The shipments are always shown, and the products for each shipment are shown in a RowDetails, that becomes visible when I doubleclick a row.

In the DataGrid I am using a custom checkbox column:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
       Copy
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=DoCopy, Mode=TwoWay, 
             UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
       </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

My `<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>` has the same column.
What I'm looking for, is to check all items in the details view when the "main" checkbox is checked.

I have a Shipment class and a Product class. Both classes have DoCopy property.
Shipment:

```
Run through all products and set DoCopy = true
```

**Problem:**

When I click a checkbox in the DataGrid, all products' checkboxes are checked. But only if the RowDetails are not shown. If the RowDetails are shown and I click the "main" checkbox, it gets checked, but the details checkboxes doesn't.

Also if I previously have opened and closed a row details and then check the "main" checkbox, the same happens. The products' checkboxes remain unchecked.

Shipment have a `List<Product>` which contains all products for that shipment.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112857/handling-exclusive-or-conditions-when-binding-to-two-boolean-properties-in-xaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, guys.
I seems I forgot to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
It all works as it should now. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

The following code works for me. I simply want to select all the check box of a datagrid on some event. The following code simply checked all the check boxes inside a datagrid. In my case column zero is a checkbox column

```
private void SelectAll()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dgVehicle.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dgVehicle.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);

            if (row != null)
            {
                CheckBox chk = dgVehicle.Columns[0].GetCellContent(row) as CheckBox;
                chk.IsChecked = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

thakrage,
the easiest way to handle this, use click event for every "copy" checkbox row, in that event you can set Docopy=true or watever you like to do...

then define a check box outside a datagrid and then set the margin to place the checkbox  exactly as like Data Header and bubble a click event to check all the rows.

refer my sample code below:

```
<CheckBox Name="chkbox_chkall" Click="chkbox_chkall_Click" Content="Check all" BorderBrush="#FF828282" Foreground="#FF5B585A"/>
```

and

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
       <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=DoCopy, Mode=TwoWay, 
         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Click="chkBoxRow_Click"
   </DataTemplate>
```

in CodeBehind:

```
    private void chkbox_chkall_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chkbox_chkall = sender as CheckBox;
        foreach (OnlineActivatedProducts rowItem in (grdProducts.ItemsSource))
        {
            CheckBox chk = grdProducts.Columns[6].GetCellContent(rowItem) as CheckBox;
            if (chkbox_chkall.IsChecked == true)
            {
                chk.IsChecked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                chk.IsChecked = false;
            }
            chkBoxRow_Click(chk, e); // which bubbles each rows checked / unchecked event
        }
    } 

    private void chkBoxRow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (chkBoxContent.IsChecked.Value)
        {
            //if checked do something here 
        }
        else if (!chkBoxContent.IsChecked.Value)
        {
            //if unchecked do something here
        }
    }
```